# How to open a file automatically in windows xp when i Insert USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb-drive, autorun

I want to open a file when i insert USB drive on system without open auto-run dialog windows. when i insert USB drive file automatically execute without knowing and silently it will not display auto-run dialog box to open a file how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something supported by Windows, for obvious security reasons.

You're free to change Group Policy settings on the machine, provided you have local (or domain) Administrative access - otherwise you can't, and you shouldn't.